# Não sei usar o método de converter imagens no xamarin.forms.image

Tags: c#, array, xamarin-forms

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo *xamarin.forms* e estou tendo dificuldade em entender como preencher o parâmetro para converter uma imagem em array de bytes, pesquisei muito procurando alguma solução, achei esse método a seguir para converter para array de bytes.

```
public object ConvertImageInArrayByte( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        ImageSource retSource = null;
        if (value != null)
        {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = (byte[])value;
            retSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));
        }
        return retSource;
    }
```

A imagem esta carregada no xaml:

```
 <Image x:Name="fotosOcorrencia" HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="{Binding Foto}"  HeightRequest="180"/>
```

Mas não estou sabendo preencher os parâmetros, não achei em lugar nem um como fazer isso. Estou tentando fazer isso:

```
 arrayByteImagem = ConvertImageInArrayByte(fotosOcorrencia, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Sou muito grato por alguém poder me ajudar, sei que não é difícil, mas não to conseguindo achar a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Galera encontrei outra forma de converter imagem em array de byte que resolveu meu problema.
Mas mesmo assim se alguém souber me explicar como usar o método que mostrei eu agradeço.
Essa foi a solução

```
public static byte[] GetPhoto(string filePath)
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(
            filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

        byte[] photo = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

        reader.Close();
        stream.Close();

        return photo;
    }
```

Comment: Isso tudo pode ser reduzido para um `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);`.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos analisar este método. Há vários defeitos nele, vou explicar um por um.

1. Os parâmetros do método `culture`, `parameter` e `targetType` nunca foram usados.
2. Como você quer converter uma imagem para um array de bytes, a entrada principal do método devia ser uma imagem. Por que que é um `object`, descrito no parâmetro `value`?
3. A saída do método devia ser um array de bytes, mas também retorna um `object`.
4. Na seguinte linha, esse tipo de conversão **não existe**.

   ```
   byte[] imageAsBytes = (byte[])value; // você não pode converter um object
                                        // para byte[] diretamente
   ```
5. A conversão estaria errada se você usasse o método como um `byte[]` porque ele retorna um `ImageSource`:

   ```
   ImageSource retSource = null;
   ...
   return retSource;
   ```

---

`Object` é a base de todos os tipos presentes no .NET Framework, ele pode herdar qualquer tipo, até os que você não quer passar como parâmetro.

---

Vamos arrumar isso, você quer converter uma imagem para byte[], né? Então vamos fazer isso da maneira certa.

```
// um método que dele sai um array de bytes e entra uma imagem
public byte[] ConvertImageInArrayByte(System.Drawing.Image value)
{
   // aqui criamos uma memória temporária para salvar a imagem nela
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
      // salvamos uma cópia da nossa imagem na nossa memória virtual
      value.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
      // retornamos os bytes da memória virtual
      return ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

Como o stream da memória foi criado num bloco `using`, ela é automaticamente descartada após o seu uso.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem toda razão, achei estranho mesmo ter que passar um tipo objeto para transformar em array de byte sendo que o retorno é objeto. Eu vi alguém usando esse método, acho que ele devia estar usando esse método no no DataBinding do xaml.
Essa solução que você me passou funciona mesmo no .Net (System.Drawing.Image), mas parece que não tem como converter quando estamos no Xamarin porque ele é uma imagem xamarin.forms.image e me da um erro falando que não tem como eu transformar Drawing.image em Forms.image.
Mas nesse tempo encontrei também mais outra solução galera. Agora pelo arquivo.
Aproveitei e também transformei em Base64.

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
byte[] arrayByteImagem = memoryStream.ToArray();
string temp_inBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(arrayByteImagem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, pessoal. Estou tentando converter image para bytes e bytes para imagem.. Meu cadastro de livros , vai precisar cadastrar a imagem da capa do livro no sqlite.

```
// um método que dele sai um array de bytes e entra uma imagem 
public byte[] ConvertImageInArrayByte(System.Drawing.Image value) { 
  // aqui criamos uma memória temporária para salvar a imagem nela 
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) { 
  // salvamos uma cópia da nossa imagem na nossa memória virtual 
  value.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
  // retornamos os bytes da memória virtual 
  return ms.ToArray(); } 
}
```

O problema que essa solução não funciona diretamente no projeto compartilhado, só funciona no projeto nativo Android.

Aí com isso, criei um dependecy service e tentei passar a imagem como parametro para ser resolvida no projeto android e consequentemente retornar os byte[]'s... Porém dá erro , pois estou passando como parâmetro uma XamarinForms.Image e o Android espera receber System.Drawing.Image. Com fazer nesse caso?

Converter um objeto Xamarin.Forms.Image para System.Drawing.Image?